# Why can't I find P(A and B) by P(A)*P(B) on contingency table?

Tags: probability, statistics

A random sample of 215 students were asked if they preferred reading magazines, doing outdoor sports, or playing an instrument.

The table gives us that there are 113 females that answered.

So P(Female)=$\frac{113}{215}$.

The table also gives us that 50 students total said they preferred reading.

So P(Reading)=$\frac{50}{215}$.

Then the table shows that 42 females said they preferred reading.

So P(Female and Reading)=$\frac{42}{215}$.

However, using the probability rule for P(A and B)=P(A)*P(B),
notice that $\frac{113}{215}*\frac{50}{215}=\frac{5650}{46225}=0.122\neq 0.195=\frac{42}{215}$.

Why is this?

Comment: By definition we have $P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ exactly when the events are independent.  So your inequality means that these events are not independent.

Comment: There is no rule that says $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$.  Just think about it, you should easily be able to produce counterexamples.  That relation defines *independent* events, which these are not,

Comment: Could you explain why they are not independent?

Comment: Because $P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)\times P(B)$.  That's the definition.

Comment: Often the purpose of a chi-squared test is to judge whether row and column categories (3.g.,gender and preference) are independent. Then the null hypothesis is that they are independent. According, 'expected'.  cell counts are computed under the assumption of independence. Then if 'expected' and 'observed' counts disagree markedly, the null hypothesis of independence is rejected. // In order to give a helpful answer to your question, it would be helpful if you told us what you are studying and what goal you have in mind for the answer.